# python scrapy not crawling all urls in scraped list

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape information from the pages listed on this page.
https://pardo.ch/pardo/program/archive/2017/catalog-films.html

the xpath selector:

```
film_page_urls_startpage = sel.xpath('//article[@class="strip-list_link_all strip-list strip--color row row--5"]/a/@href').extract()
```

correctly scrapes all 23 urls. however, the spider doesn't even appear to try crawling all 23. it crawls only 11. the same 11 each time. since I'm using selenium, I can see it just jump right over the first page/url without ever navigating to it at all. what gives?

this is my code:

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from time import sleep
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from films_locarno.items import FilmsLocarnoItemfrom scrapy import 

class FilmsLocarnoSpiderSpider(Spider):
name = 'films_locarno_spider'
allowed_domains = ['https://pardo.ch/']
start_urls = ['https://pardo.ch/pardo/program/archive/2017/catalog-films.html']

def start_requests(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.get('https://pardo.ch/pardo/program/archive/2017/catalog-films.html')
    sel = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)

    #grab list of start pages for all 4/5 editions of festival available
    #list of film page urls on start page (letter A)
    film_page_urls_startpage = sel.xpath('//article[@class="strip-    list_link_all strip-list strip--color row row--5"]/a/@href').extract()
    film_page_urls_startpage_full = []
    for url in film_page_urls_startpage:
        film_page_fullurl = "https://pardo.ch" + url
        film_page_urls_startpage_full.append(film_page_fullurl)

    #navigate to startpage film_pages
    for url3 in film_page_urls_startpage_full:
        self.driver.get(url3)
        sel = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
        self.logger.info('Sleeping for 1 second')
        sleep(1)
        yield Request(url3, callback=self.parse_filmpage)
        self.logger.info('Sleeping for 2 seconds')
        sleep(2)
```

my output log reads [you can ignore the ERROR, its only a page navigation error, since fixed]:

```
    2017-12-26 09:29:33 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: films_locarno)
2017-12-26 09:29:33 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'SPIDER_MODULES': ['films_locarno.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'films_locarno', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'films_locarno.spiders', 'FEED_URI': 'films_locarno6.csv', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv'}
2017-12-26 09:29:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter']
2017-12-26 09:29:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-12-26 09:29:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-12-26 09:29:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline']
2017-12-26 09:29:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-12-26 09:29:33 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-12-26 09:29:33 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2017-12-26 09:29:34 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:54941/session {"capabilities": {"firstMatch": [], "alwaysMatch": {"browserName": "firefox", "acceptInsecureCerts": true}}, "desiredCapabilities": {"browserName": "firefox", "acceptInsecureCerts": true}}
2017-12-26 09:29:41 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-26 09:29:41 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:54941/session/1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a/url {"sessionId": "1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a", "url": "https://pardo.ch/pardo/program/archive/2017/catalog-films.html"}
2017-12-26 09:29:52 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-26 09:29:52 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:54941/session/1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a/source {"sessionId": "1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a"}
2017-12-26 09:29:52 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-26 09:29:52 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:54941/session/1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a/url {"sessionId": "1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a", "url": "https://pardo.ch/pardo/program/archive/2017/film.html?fid=955449&eid=70"}
2017-12-26 09:29:56 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-26 09:29:56 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:54941/session/1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a/source {"sessionId": "1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a"}
2017-12-26 09:29:56 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-26 09:29:56 [films_locarno_spider] INFO: Sleeping for 1 second
2017-12-26 09:29:57 [films_locarno_spider] INFO: Sleeping for 2 seconds
2017-12-26 09:29:59 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:54941/session/1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a/url {"sessionId": "1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a", "url": "https://pardo.ch/pardo/program/archive/2017/film.html?fid=959423&eid=70"}
2017-12-26 09:30:03 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-26 09:30:03 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:54941/session/1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a/source {"sessionId": "1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a"}
2017-12-26 09:30:03 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-26 09:30:03 [films_locarno_spider] INFO: Sleeping for 1 second
2017-12-26 09:30:04 [films_locarno_spider] INFO: Sleeping for 2 seconds
2017-12-26 09:30:06 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:54941/session/1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a/url {"sessionId": "1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a", "url": "https://pardo.ch/pardo/program/archive/2017/film.html?fid=968681&eid=70"}
2017-12-26 09:30:09 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-26 09:30:09 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:54941/session/1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a/source {"sessionId": "1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a"}
2017-12-26 09:30:09 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-26 09:30:09 [films_locarno_spider] INFO: Sleeping for 1 second
2017-12-26 09:30:10 [films_locarno_spider] INFO: Sleeping for 2 seconds
2017-12-26 09:30:12 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:54941/session/1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a/url {"sessionId": "1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a", "url": "https://pardo.ch/pardo/program/archive/2017/film.html?fid=959475&eid=70"}
2017-12-26 09:30:14 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-26 09:30:14 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:54941/session/1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a/source {"sessionId": "1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a"}
2017-12-26 09:30:14 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-26 09:30:14 [films_locarno_spider] INFO: Sleeping for 1 second
2017-12-26 09:30:15 [films_locarno_spider] INFO: Sleeping for 2 seconds
2017-12-26 09:30:17 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:54941/session/1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a/url {"sessionId": "1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a", "url": "https://pardo.ch/pardo/program/archive/2017/film.html?fid=960897&eid=70"}
2017-12-26 09:30:19 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-26 09:30:19 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:54941/session/1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a/source {"sessionId": "1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a"}
2017-12-26 09:30:19 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-26 09:30:19 [films_locarno_spider] INFO: Sleeping for 1 second
2017-12-26 09:30:20 [films_locarno_spider] INFO: Sleeping for 2 seconds
2017-12-26 09:30:22 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:54941/session/1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a/url {"sessionId": "1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a", "url": "https://pardo.ch/pardo/program/archive/2017/film.html?fid=960706&eid=70"}
2017-12-26 09:30:25 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-26 09:30:25 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:54941/session/1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a/source {"sessionId": "1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a"}
2017-12-26 09:30:25 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-26 09:30:25 [films_locarno_spider] INFO: Sleeping for 1 second
2017-12-26 09:30:26 [films_locarno_spider] INFO: Sleeping for 2 seconds
2017-12-26 09:30:28 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:54941/session/1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a/url {"sessionId": "1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a", "url": "https://pardo.ch/pardo/program/archive/2017/film.html?fid=929220&eid=70"}
2017-12-26 09:30:32 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-26 09:30:32 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:54941/session/1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a/source {"sessionId": "1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a"}
2017-12-26 09:30:32 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-26 09:30:32 [films_locarno_spider] INFO: Sleeping for 1 second
2017-12-26 09:30:33 [films_locarno_spider] INFO: Sleeping for 2 seconds
2017-12-26 09:30:35 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:54941/session/1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a/url {"sessionId": "1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a", "url": "https://pardo.ch/pardo/program/archive/2017/film.html?fid=960742&eid=70"}
2017-12-26 09:30:38 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-26 09:30:38 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:54941/session/1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a/source {"sessionId": "1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a"}
2017-12-26 09:30:38 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-26 09:30:38 [films_locarno_spider] INFO: Sleeping for 1 second
2017-12-26 09:30:39 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-12-26 09:30:39 [films_locarno_spider] INFO: Sleeping for 2 seconds
2017-12-26 09:30:41 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:54941/session/1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a/url {"sessionId": "1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a", "url": "https://pardo.ch/pardo/program/archive/2017/film.html?fid=960703&eid=70"}
2017-12-26 09:30:44 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-26 09:30:44 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:54941/session/1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a/source {"sessionId": "1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a"}
2017-12-26 09:30:44 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-26 09:30:44 [films_locarno_spider] INFO: Sleeping for 1 second
2017-12-26 09:30:45 [films_locarno_spider] INFO: Sleeping for 2 seconds
2017-12-26 09:30:47 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:54941/session/1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a/url {"sessionId": "1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a", "url": "https://pardo.ch/pardo/program/archive/2017/film.html?fid=963699&eid=70"}
2017-12-26 09:30:50 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-26 09:30:50 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:54941/session/1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a/source {"sessionId": "1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a"}
2017-12-26 09:30:50 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-26 09:30:50 [films_locarno_spider] INFO: Sleeping for 1 second
2017-12-26 09:30:51 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://pardo.ch/pardo/program/archive/2017/film.html?fid=955449&eid=70> (referer: None)
2017-12-26 09:30:51 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://pardo.ch/pardo/program/archive/2017/film.html?fid=959423&eid=70> (referer: None)
2017-12-26 09:30:51 [films_locarno_spider] INFO: Sleeping for 2 seconds
2017-12-26 09:30:54 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:54941/session/1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a/url {"sessionId": "1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a", "url": "https://pardo.ch/pardo/program/archive/2017/film.html?fid=964462&eid=70"}
2017-12-26 09:30:58 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-26 09:30:58 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:54941/session/1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a/source {"sessionId": "1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a"}
2017-12-26 09:30:58 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-26 09:30:58 [films_locarno_spider] INFO: Sleeping for 1 second
2017-12-26 09:30:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://pardo.ch/pardo/program/archive/2017/film.html?fid=968681&eid=70> (referer: None)
2017-12-26 09:30:59 [films_locarno_spider] INFO: Sleeping for 3 seconds
2017-12-26 09:31:02 [films_locarno_spider] INFO: Sleeping for 3 seconds
2017-12-26 09:31:05 [films_locarno_spider] INFO: Sleeping for 2 seconds
2017-12-26 09:31:07 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:54941/session/1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a/url {"sessionId": "1a43ebe2-5161-ba45-acd6-31534994c97a", "url": "https://pardo.ch<a href=\"?finit=B\" class=\"dd__list__link\">B</a>"}
2017-12-26 09:31:07 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-12-26 09:31:07 [scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Error while obtaining start requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 127, in _next_request
    request = next(slot.start_requests)
  File "/Users/MNK1/Desktop/films_locarno/films_locarno/spiders/films_locarno_spider.py", line 48, in start_requests
    self.driver.get(films_list_page)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 268, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Malformed URL: https://pardo.ch<a href="?finit=B" class="dd__list__link">B</a> is not a valid URL.

2017-12-26 09:31:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://pardo.ch/pardo/program/archive/2017/film.html?fid=959475&eid=70> (referer: None)
2017-12-26 09:31:07 [films_locarno_spider] INFO: Sleeping for 3 seconds
2017-12-26 09:31:10 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://pardo.ch:443/mirror/get.do?q=80&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebfiles.pardo.ch%2Fperm%2F3001%2F104%2FOC956584_P3001_233104.jpeg&w=539&h=296> referred in <None>
2017-12-26 09:31:10 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://pardo.ch:443/mirror/get.do?q=80&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebfiles.pardo.ch%2Fperm%2F3001%2F970%2FOC960622_P3001_233970.jpg&w=539&h=296> referred in <None>
2017-12-26 09:31:10 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://pardo.ch/pardo/program/archive/2017/film.html?fid=960897&eid=70> (referer: None)
2017-12-26 09:31:10 [films_locarno_spider] INFO: Sleeping for 3 seconds
2017-12-26 09:31:13 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (uptodate): Downloaded image from <GET https://pardo.ch:443/mirror/get.do?q=80&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebfiles.pardo.ch%2Fperm%2F3001%2F430%2FOC973705_P3001_240430.jpg&w=539&h=296> referred in <None>
2017-12-26 09:31:13 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://pardo.ch/pardo/program/archive/2017/film.html?fid=960706&eid=70> (referer: None)
2017-12-26 09:31:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://pardo.ch/pardo/program/archive/2017/film.html?fid=955449&eid=70>
{'color': ['Color'],
 'country': ['Pakistan, USA'],
 'director': [''],
 'festival_edition': ['70th'],
 'festival_year': ['2017'],
 'film_year': ['2015'],
 'format_': ['DCP'],
 'image_urls': ['https://pardo.ch:443/mirror/get.do?q=80&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebfiles.pardo.ch%2Fperm%2F3001%2F104%2FOC956584_P3001_233104.jpeg&w=539&h=296'],
 'images': [{'checksum': '89dd9751e436eed7ae35f980c2e10bc3',
             'path': 'full/53cb39b642dcd6cea1e7898c9dc4777b844ea4fd.jpg',
             'url': 'https://pardo.ch:443/mirror/get.do?q=80&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebfiles.pardo.ch%2Fperm%2F3001%2F104%2FOC956584_P3001_233104.jpeg&w=539&h=296'}],
 'language': ['Urdu'],
 'length': ["40'"],
 'program': ['Open Doors: Screenings'],
 'title': ['A Girl in the River: The Price of Forgiveness']}
2017-12-26 09:31:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://pardo.ch/pardo/program/archive/2017/film.html?fid=959423&eid=70>
{'color': ['Color'],
 'country': ['Switzerland'],
 'director': [''],
 'festival_edition': ['70th'],
 'festival_year': ['2017'],
 'film_year': ['2017'],
 'format_': ['DCP'],
 'image_urls': ['https://pardo.ch:443/mirror/get.do?q=80&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebfiles.pardo.ch%2Fperm%2F3001%2F970%2FOC960622_P3001_233970.jpg&w=539&h=296'],
 'images': [{'checksum': 'cce5e9ffd3bad2b359c489ac4c51c25e',
             'path': 'full/84e0d100fc90acf2c0cfe8c38454a305e23b7408.jpg',
             'url': 'https://pardo.ch:443/mirror/get.do?q=80&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebfiles.pardo.ch%2Fperm%2F3001%2F970%2FOC960622_P3001_233970.jpg&w=539&h=296'}],

[[edited for length]]


2017-12-26 09:31:35 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 3038,
 'downloader/request_count': 11,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 11,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 115519,
 'downloader/response_count': 11,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 11,
 'file_count': 11,
 'file_status_count/uptodate': 11,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 26, 17, 31, 35, 820684),
 'item_scraped_count': 11,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 86,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 43,
 'memusage/max': 79556608,
 'memusage/startup': 66007040,
 'response_received_count': 11,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 11,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 11,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 11,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 11,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 26, 17, 29, 33, 860768)}
2017-12-26 09:31:35 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: so you are visiting those urls with selenium and also with scrapy?

Comment: hello, yes i am.

Comment: can we know the reason? if you are visiting the site already with Selenium, then there is no need to do it again with Scrapy

Comment: hi, yes, i am generating a screencast of the process while running the spider - its for work/education.

Comment: please remove that comment or update your question with it. That is unreadable.

Comment: done, thanks. appended to top of code block.

Comment: please share your logs when executing this spider, and most importantly the final stats that scrapy gives at the end.

Comment: output log [edited for length] placed in question above.

Comment: `len(film_page_urls_startpage)` gives me 11, not 23. So your xpath doesn't work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I checked this

```
len(film_page_urls_startpage)
```

and I get only 11, not 23.

If I use `xpath('//article/a/@href')` then I get 23 urls.

There is no need to add `@class`. There is no other `article`.

---

**EDIT:**

If I do

```
for item in sel.xpath('//article/@class').extract():
    print('class:', item)
```

then I get

```
class: strip-list_link_all strip-list strip--color row row--5 even
class: strip-list_link_all strip-list strip--color row row--5
class: strip-list_link_all strip-list strip--color row row--5 even
class: strip-list_link_all strip-list strip--color row row--5
class: strip-list_link_all strip-list strip--color row row--5 even
class: strip-list_link_all strip-list strip--color row row--5
class: strip-list_link_all strip-list strip--color row row--5 even
class: strip-list_link_all strip-list strip--color row row--5
class: strip-list_link_all strip-list strip--color row row--5 even
class: strip-list_link_all strip-list strip--color row row--5
class: strip-list_link_all strip-list strip--color row row--5 even
class: strip-list_link_all strip-list strip--color row row--5
class: strip-list_link_all strip-list strip--color row row--5 even
class: strip-list_link_all strip-list strip--color row row--5
class: strip-list_link_all strip-list strip--color row row--5 even
class: strip-list_link_all strip-list strip--color row row--5
class: strip-list_link_all strip-list strip--color row row--5 even
class: strip-list_link_all strip-list strip--color row row--5
class: strip-list_link_all strip-list strip--color row row--5 even
class: strip-list_link_all strip-list strip--color row row--5
class: strip-list_link_all strip-list strip--color row row--5 even
class: strip-list_link_all strip-list strip--color row row--5
class: strip-list_link_all strip-list strip--color row row--5 even
```

So some items have `even` in class string and this was your problem.

Comment: thanks so much! this is incredibly helpful. it solves the problem. and shows how to identify the cause in the future. i'm somewhat baffled by the flaw in my workflow that produced it. if it type 'response.xpath('//article[@class="strip-list_link_all strip-list strip--color row row--5"]/a/@href').extract()' in the scrapy shell, it returns a list of 23 urls. can this be due to some difference between selenium in a .py file and the scrapy shell? thanks so much again!

Comment: in shell check `response.xpath('//article/@class').extract()` and you get 23 strings without `even`. Some portals can send different content for different devices. It can depends on HTTP header `"User-Agent"` or other elements like other headers or cookies. So it could recognize shell as different device that full script.

Comment: BTW: `scrapy shell` and normal `scrapy` scritpt doesn't run JavaScript but `Selenium` runs `JavaScript` so server may send different content. BTW: Google sends different content for client which doesn't run JavaScript - it sends not only with different classes but also in different tags - it uses `<table><tr><td>` instead of `<div>`.

Comment: I don't know why use `Selenium` if you can do the same without `Selenium` and it will work faster. I put code without `Selenium` on GitHub: [python-examples/__scraping__/pardo.ch - scrapy - selenium/](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/__scraping__/pardo.ch%20-%20scrapy%20-%20selenium)

Comment: thanks furas, this is incredibly helpful, i never suspected there could be such a discrepancy. i'm using selenium to generate a screencast of the scraping process, as part of promoting webscraping as a tool of research at an educational institution. not ideal from the point of view of speed, but visually interesting when exploiting selenium's webdriver.