# Scrapy not scraping all items on a page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm scraping a e-commerce site which has 48 products on each page except the last page.

I'm using Scrapy for this. The problem is, it is not scraping all products from the page. For example, it scrapes 12 from page 1, 18 from 2, 10 from 3, 19 from 4, and so on. It should scrape all 48 products from each page, but it doesn't.

Below is my script. For the last 2 days, I can't figure out what am I doing wrong.

**UPDATE**
I deduped the url list before scraping and added log messages to find out what the issue is.  Current code:

```
import scrapy
from productspider.items import Product
from urlparse import urlparse


class Ecommerce(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ecommerce"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        urls = kwargs.pop('urls', [])
        if urls:
            self.start_urls = urls.split(',')
        self.logger.info(self.start_urls)
        super(Ecommerce, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    page = 1
    parse_product_called = 0

    def parse(self, response):

        url = response.url
        if url.endswith('/'):
            url = url.rstrip('/')

        o = urlparse(url)

        products = response.xpath(
            "//a[contains(@href, '" + o.path + "/products/')]/@href").extract()

        if not products:
            raise scrapy.exceptions.CloseSpider("All products scraped")

        products = dedupe(products)

        self.logger.info("Products found on page %s = %s" % (self.page, len(products)))
        for product in products:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(product), self.parse_product)

        self.page += 1
        next_page = o.path + "?page=" + str(self.page)
        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page), self.parse)

    def parse_product(self, response):

        self.parse_product_called += 1
        self.logger.info("Parse product called %s time" % self.parse_product_called)

        product = Product()
        product["name"] = response.xpath(
            "//meta[@property='og:title']/@content")[0].extract()
        product["price"] = response.xpath(
            "//meta[@property='og:price:amount']/@content")[0].extract()

        return product

def dedupe(seq, idfun=None):
   if idfun is None:
       def idfun(x): return x
   seen = {}
   result = []
   for item in seq:
       marker = idfun(item)
       if marker in seen: continue
       seen[marker] = 1
       result.append(item)
   return result
```

Scrapy log after crawling:

```
2017-12-30 13:18:55 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 86621,
 'downloader/request_count': 203,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 203,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 10925361,
 'downloader/response_count': 203,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 203,
 'finish_reason': 'All products scraped',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 30, 7, 48, 55, 370000),
 'item_scraped_count': 193,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 397,
 'log_count/INFO': 210,
 'request_depth_max': 9,
 'response_received_count': 203,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 203,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 203,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 418,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 418,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 30, 7, 48, 22, 405000)}
2017-12-30 13:18:55 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (All products scraped)
```

And the log messages:

> 2017-12-30 13:18:25 [ecommerce] INFO: Products found on page 1 = 48
>
> 2017-12-30 13:18:32 [ecommerce] INFO: Products found on page 2 = 48
>
> 2017-12-30 13:18:35 [ecommerce] INFO: Products found on page 3 = 48
>
> 2017-12-30 13:18:38 [ecommerce] INFO: Products found on page 4 = 48
>
> 2017-12-30 13:18:41 [ecommerce] INFO: Products found on page 5 = 48
>
> 2017-12-30 13:18:43 [ecommerce] INFO: Products found on page 6 = 48
>
> 2017-12-30 13:18:45 [ecommerce] INFO: Products found on page 7 = 48
>
> 2017-12-30 13:18:48 [ecommerce] INFO: Products found on page 8 = 48
>
> 2017-12-30 13:18:51 [ecommerce] INFO: Products found on page 9 = 24

The log "Parse product called" was printed each time parse_product was called. The last log message is:

> 2017-12-30 13:18:55 [ecommerce] INFO: Parse product called 193 time

As you can see, it found a total of 408 products but called the `parse_product` function just 193. Hence only 193 items were scraped.

Comment: Add a `print (len(products))` and see what counts you get? There might be a issue with your Xpath

Comment: better add url to question - and then we can check page. Different pages may need different solutions. So some may need `Selenium` other may need only different `xpath` because page sends different content for client which runs JavaScript and different for other clients. ie. Google Search sends items in different tags. The same problem in [python scrapy not crawling all urls in scraped list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48015404/python-scrapy-not-crawling-all-urls-in-scraped-list). It uses different tags in scrapy which doesn't run JS and different in Selenium or browser which run JS.

Comment: @TarunLalwani I updated my question with log messages.

Comment: @furas Please see my updated question, I added some log messages. You can see that It found all products but didn't called the parse function for all products.

Comment: if you showed urls then you would have already solved it.
 I suspect that some urls are similar to others and it filters them as duplicate. Use `print()` to display urls before `yields` and inside `parse_product`  you will see which urls are skiped.

Comment: @furas I deduped the url list before parsing them. Also if there were duplicates, scrapy shows dedupefiltered in log after crawling which it doesn't. I cannot share the url here, could you please create a chatroom?

Comment: Okie, i think your issue is this `if not products:
            raise scrapy.exceptions.CloseSpider("All products scraped")`. You are not giving your spider enough to time to scrape. When you reach the last page, you ask the scraper to literally shutdown. And it then leaves every page that has not yet been put in download queue. Hence the behavior will be different records everytime. Remove this code and it should scraper everything fine

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thanks! It worked, but now it just keeps scraping more pages and doesn't stop. How to stop it?

Comment: Then `next_page` yield should not be done when `len(products) < 48`

Comment: @TarunLalwani You're my saviour!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues in your code

**Shutting the scraper down**

```
if not products:
   raise scrapy.exceptions.CloseSpider("All products scraped")
```

Using above you request the spider to terminate as soon as it can. This is not a good thing to do. This is only used when you don't want the scraping to continue

**Not ending the scraper**

```
self.page += 1
next_page = o.path + "?page=" + str(self.page)
yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page), self.parse)
```

You have an uncontrolled paging logic which needs to end. So you can use the fact that any page which doesn't have 48 products is the last page

```
self.page += 1
next_page = o.path + "?page=" + str(self.page)
if len(products) == 48:
   yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page), self.parse)
```

Comment: It should be actually `if products: yeild scrapy.Request...` as the last page doesn't always have exact 48 products.

Comment: Not necessarily, If current page has 47 products or less, I know there is no point in going for next page as it will have 0 products. On a edge case it is possible that last page has exact 48 products and this will go to the next page which will have 0 products and then the loop will end. Your `if products` will always browser a extra page which can be and should be avoided