# Scrapy only scraping a few items

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, playwright

I am practicing a bit with scrapy on a website, with 60 items maximum per page. For each item, I need to extract more data, so I go to each items' url. However, I am only able to scrape a fraction (around 14 items) from the first page (but it crawls at least all items). [It is similar to this question, but it does not help in my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48028041/scrapy-not-scraping-all-items-on-a-page). My code is the following:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod
from product_spider.items import ProductItem


class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "product_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["billa.at"]
    base_url = "https://shop.billa.at/"
    
    def start_requests(self):
        url = "https://shop.billa.at/warengruppe/getraenke/alkoholfreie-getraenke/mineralwasser-mit-geschmack/B2-318"
        yield scrapy.Request(url, meta=dict(
            page = 1,
            playwright = True,
            playwright_include_page = True,
            playwright_page_methods = [
                PageMethod("wait_for_selector", "a.product__content-title-sc-link"), 
            ],
            errback = self.errback,
        ), callback=self.temp_parse)         


    def temp_parse(self, response):
        
        # extract all product urls of a page
        all_product_urls_of_a_page = response.css("a.product__content-title-sc-link ::attr(href)").getall()
        
        #if not all_product_urls_of_a_page:
        #    raise scrapy.exceptions.CloseSpider("All products scraped")
        
        for url in all_product_urls_of_a_page:
            product_url = self.base_url + url
            yield scrapy.Request(product_url, meta=dict(
                playwright = True,
                playwright_include_page = True,
                playwright_page_methods = [
                    PageMethod("wait_for_selector", "img.loaded.fade-in"),
                ],
                errback = self.errback,
            ), callback=self.parse_product_page)
        
        # check if there is a next page
        if not response.css("button.pagination__item.pagination__item--next.ng-scope ::attr(disabled)"):
            next_page_url = response.url + f"?page={response.meta['page'] + 1}"
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, meta=dict(
                page = response.meta['page'] + 1,
                playwright = True,
                playwright_include_page = True,
                playwright_page_methods = [
                    PageMethod("wait_for_selector", "a.product__content-title-sc-link"), 
                ],
                errback = self.errback,
            ), callback=self.temp_parse)          
        
    async def errback(self, failure):
        print("IN ERRBACK")
        page = failure.request.meta["playwright_page"]
        await page.close()
        
    def parse_product_page(self, response):
               
        product_item = ProductItem()
        
        product_item["product"] = response.css("img.loaded.fade-in ::attr(alt)").extract_first()
        product_item["image_url"] = response.css("img.loaded.fade-in ::attr(src)").extract_first()
        
        yield product_item
```

I was able to scrape all items using selenium. However, I would prefer scrapy, due to its speed.

Comment: is the image really the only information your are trying to extract?

Comment: For now yes. But the problem is, that even this is not working, while with selenium it works. Any idea why it is not working?

Comment: probably because the additional items aren't loaded until they scrolled into view.

Comment: I added scrolling (with `PageMethod("evaluate", "window.scrollBy(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")` in `start_requests(self)`), but unfortunately it did not help. I am able to crawl all items, but the issue is, that it only parses a fraction of it (i.e., `parse_product_page(self, response)` is only called around 14 times).